# Use p() function mule to fetch secure property in dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a encrypted value in my property file  using mule secure property
eg:

```
password = !#$#%%%f  (encrypted)
```

I want to dynamically fetch this value unencrypted using the p function in dataweave based on the input parameter passed in the request

I get the encrypted value using this syntax

```
Mule::p(vars.password)
```

How do i use the secure::   syntax on top of this to decrypt the value

```
{
    password: Mule::p('secure::vars.password')
}
```

Can someone tell the correct way to do it in Mule 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To access a property defined in the secure property placeholder use the following syntax:

```
p('secure::myproperty.name')
```

If the key is dynamic use string concatenation:

```
p('secure::' ++ vars.password)
```